# Help with fundamental proof (triangle inequality)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

From page 11 (4th edition Spivak's calculus).

First off, a definition for $|a|$ would be  $$\left| a \right| = \begin{cases}
 a, \qquad a \geq 0 \\ 
 -a, \qquad a \leq 0 
\end{cases}$$

Theorem: For all numbers $a$ and $b$, we have $$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$$

and concentrating only on 1 of the 4 cases ie let $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$  we have

$|a+b| = a + b = |a| + |b|$

It's the second and third expression, the assertion that $a + b = |a| + |b|$ that is unclear to me. Clearly $|a+b|$ must be $\geq 0$, and by definition allows the assertion $|a + b| = a + b$.

Perhaps another question might shed some light. Assume that $z \geq 0$. Can I simply thus assert that $ z = |z|$? If this sounds a little confusing, it's probably because I am missing something.

Comment: By your definition, yes $z\geq 0\iff |z|=z$ (for real $z$ btw)

Comment: It's truly that simple??  Reals, understood  :-)

Comment: Absolute value means non-negative value so naturally          
  $z \ge 0 \implies  |z|=z$

Comment: One could also use the Fundamental theorem of Absolute values, i.e., $-M \leq a \leq M \iff |a| \leq M$. Apply this for two real numbers $a, b$ -- where $M=|a|$ and $M=|b|$ respectively -- and add the inequality to get your desired expression to prove the theorem. This approach I find much nicer than 4 uninteresting cases.

Comment: Notice that the definition of $|a+b|$ would be  
$$\left| a+b \right| = \begin{cases}
 a+b, \qquad a+b \geq 0 \\ 
 -(a+b), \qquad a+b \leq 0 
\end{cases}$$
by which
$$\left| a \right| = \begin{cases}
 a, \qquad a \geq 0 \\ 
 -a, \qquad a \leq 0 
\end{cases},\quad \left| b \right| = \begin{cases}
 b, \qquad b \geq 0 \\ 
 -b, \qquad b \leq 0 
\end{cases}$$
therefore for $a,b\ge 0: |a+b|= a+b = |a|+|b|$.

Comment: @Owen Sorry for the delay... that's what surgery does. Thank you very much. Making a lot more sense.

Comment: @Axion004  That's very very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try squaring both sides and noting $|a+b|^2 = (a+b)^2$

This is a classic approach

Comment: Thank you for your input.